# Comparing the performance of ECC/RSA with post quantum protocols

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, performance

I wanted to compare the performance of different cryptographic systems. There is a pretty good [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/047.pdf) comparing the 3rd round finalists of the NIST competition.

I was wondering if there are good performance comparisons of those PQ-Protocols and modern ECC/RSA protocols (e.g. Curve25519). Sadly I couldn't find a good paper about that. Neither for comparing the number of mathematical operations nor for real life experiments on the same hardware.

Therefore: Does somebody know a good paper or source for that? If not, can you give well thought on the performance differences?

Comment: This is very broad again. How about you use the answer to your previous question about PQ algorithms, distill the numbers from there [you accepted the answer] and have a go at doing the comparison. From your profile, you should be able enough to at least start to answer this question yourself.

Comment: There's a nice table at https://blog.cloudflare.com/sizing-up-post-quantum-signatures/ which gives you a rough overview of how different PQ schemes compare in terms of key sizes and speeds, and how they compare to say RSA. (It's only for signatures, but still it may be useful.)

Comment: @TMM Something like this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! But does this also exist for the key agreements/KEM?